# @UiThreadTest Unresolved Reference

Tags: android, android-testing

I need a test to run on the UI thread, so I want to use the `UiThreadTest` annotation, but it's not resolving that annotation. I'm guessing I have to include a dependency in the gradle file, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

```
@Test
@UiThreadTest
fun insertMultipleDelete() {
```

My module's build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.0'

    def nav_version = "2.3.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    def room_version = "2.2.6"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

What do I need to do to make it resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, you have to include `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'` in your gradle file.

Found it on some German website, thanks for the stellar documentation Google.